# How do I get the path to the SQL script that is executed by Microsoft SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install some application on Windows Server 2019. The application relies on a database, so I also have SQL Server 2016 (v 13.0.1601.5) on the server. But during installation, I get an error message, basically telling me some SQL script, say "abc.sql" has encountered a problem and cannot continue. When I open SQL Server's XEven Profiler, I surely see what the problem is; it fails to create a stored procedure because of some bug in the code, something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[doSomethingNice] (**@problematicParameter** int, @nonProblematicParameter int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update [dbo].[SomeTable]
        set SomeField =**@ProblematicParameter**
    where
        SomeOtherField= @nonProblematicParameter
END
```

Of course, the problem is the casing.

XEvent Profiler kindly specifies which application runs the query, and in this case, it is Windows Installer.

```
client_app_name: Windows Installer - Unicode
```

I believe (more likely hope), if I can somehow get hold of the original script file, abc.sql, I can fix it and run it from SQL Server Management Studio. This would work since the installer program provides the option of using an existing database instead of creating a new one.

I scoured the Temp directory but could not find the said script. I know it must be somewhere on the disk. How can I find where it is? Does XEvent Profiler provide that data?

Comment: XEvent Profiler can't provide such data - it can only know about connection properties and sql commands to be executed. Your abc.sql is likely contained inside installer and it may be unpacked into some temporary location or it can even run from memory. If possible, you should ask application vendor about such things. If not possible, then I would trace all SQL traffic and try to understand, what causes errors etc - you wrote about 'casing', maybe your server collation is some case sensitive variation or something?

Comment: I see. So this is more of a Windows Installer question. But is there a way of getting hold of it? Would making the server case-insensitive solve the issue?

Comment: You could use some process monitor like tool, which records (temporary) files creation and so on; most likely such files will be deleted when installer stops however.

Comment: Can you run the install against an instance not set to have a case sensitive collation? Then it won't care that `@problematicParameter` and `@ProblematicParameter` are different and you will get all the definitions there

Comment: But if that fails they may well not have tested the app on a CS collation and you may encounter subsequent errors even if you fix all the stuff in the SQL modules

Comment: Process monitor tool sounds like a good idea. Can you recommend any?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon - but that will only help if the app pulls the SQL from a file rather than executing stuff hardcoded into the binary

Comment: I reinstalled the server using the "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" collation and the problem was solved.